# Derivation of the riemannian metric tensor for the 1D Poincaré disk model of hyperbolic geometry by the induced metric

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

### Motivation

I am trying to derive the Riemannian Metric of the Inner Disc model as presented by [by cannon et al.](http://library.msri.org/books/Book31/files/cannon.pdf) in the special case of 1 dimension. My understanding is that this is the induced metric as described by [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor#Induced_metric), but I get different results, which hints that I am missing some underlying understanding.

### Pushforward function

Let $U$ be the open Subset in $\mathbb{R}$ which denotes our inner disk model, so it is limited to $(-1,1)$. Let $\varphi$ be a continuous differential function mapping $U$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$.
Lets fix the basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $e_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $e_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$.
In this case $\varphi$ is given by the hyperbolic stereographic projection for any $x \in U$, so in our case is:
$$
\varphi : U \to \mathbb{R}^2 := \varphi(x) = \frac{2x}{1-x^2} \cdot e_1 + \frac{1+x^2}{1-x^2} e_2 
$$
The derivative of this function is
$$
\frac{\partial \varphi(x)}{\partial x} =
\frac{\partial \varphi^1}{\partial x} \cdot e_1 + \frac{\partial \varphi^2}{\partial x} \cdot e_2
  \text{ where } 
\frac{\partial \varphi^1}{\partial x} = \dfrac{2\left(x^2+1\right)}{\left(1-x^2\right)^2}
 \text{ and } 
\frac{\partial \varphi^2}{\partial x} = \dfrac{4x}{\left(1-x^2\right)^2}
$$
as can be seen [in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjSzd.png) and as [as a gif here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGQfw.gif).
Let $v,w \in T_xU$ be vectors at the tangent space at $x$, which since $U$ is 1-dimensional are just given by scalars.
Now the pushforward $\varphi_{\star}(v)$ maps $v$ from $T_xU$ to it's mapped tangent space in $\mathbb{R}^2$.
In our case this reduces to:
$$
\varphi_*(v) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{a=1}^{m} 
v^i \frac{\partial \varphi^a}{\partial x^i} e_a =  
v \frac{\partial \varphi^1}{\partial x} e_1 +
v \frac{\partial \varphi^2}{\partial x} e_2 =  
v \frac{2\left(x^2+1\right)}{\left(1-x^2\right)^2} e_1 +
v \frac{4x}{\left(1-x^2\right)^2} e_2 =  
\begin{pmatrix}
v \dfrac{2\left(x^2+1\right)}{\left(1-x^2\right)^2} \\\\
v \dfrac{4x}{\left(1-x^2\right)^2}   
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which can be seen [in this image for v = (0.5)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGTUz.png)

### Induced Metric

Now if my understanding is correct we should be able to define the riemannian metrix just by the standard scalar product in $\mathbb{R}^2$ using
$g_{x}(v,w) = \langle\varphi_{\star}(v), \varphi_{\star}(w)\rangle$ which in our case is
$$
g(v,w) = \langle\varphi_\star(v), \varphi_\star(w)\rangle = 
\frac{ 4 v w (x^2+1)^2}{(1-x^2)^4} +
\frac{ 16v w x^2}{(1-x^2)^4}
$$

This in turn gives rise of the 1 x 1 matrix form of the riemannian metric, which should be:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{ 4 dx^2 (x^2+1)^2}{(1-x^2)^4} +
\frac{ 16 dx^2 x^2}{(1-x^2)^4}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which in turn is just the line element
$$
ds^2  = \frac{ 4 dx^2 (x^2+1)^2}{(1-x^2)^4} + \frac{ 16 dx^2 x^2}{(1-x^2)^4}
$$

And now I'm stumbled, because [cannon et al.](http://library.msri.org/books/Book31/files/cannon.pdf) tell me that it is instead:
$$
ds{}_I^2 = 4 \frac{dx^2}{(1-x^2)^2}
$$
Which is similar, but different enough as can be seen [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qs8ows3xpl). Why is this the case and where did I make a mistake?

Comment: You must take the hyperbola in Lorentzian space, not Euclidean.

Comment: That seem to do the trick. If I define the inner product in $\mathbb{R}^2$ by $dy^2-dx^2$, this results in $-4 \frac{dx^2}{(x^2-1)^2}$ which can be mirrored at the x axis to get the desired result. But why is this the case? Cannon tells us that that  the indefinite inner product on the Minkowski plane restricts to a positive definite inner product on hyperbolic space, but what makes us choose it here?

Comment: I don’t understand your question. The hyperbola in the *Euclidean* plane certainly does not have constant curvature.